# How can I save a table to excel sheet with original sheet formatting in python?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have loaded the data from Excel sheet that applied cell formatting(border, merge, font..)
[image]

Then, I used a conditional statement in Python to colour the cells under certain conditions. I want to save the table with this style applied again, keeping the formatting of the original Excel sheet as below.

[image]

How can I code?
I have tried below, but I didn't get wanted.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from openpyxl import load_workbook

workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook['Tables']


# Load the DataFrame from the Excel file
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', sheet_name='Tables')

# Define the column list
column_list = df.columns.to_list()[3:]

# Define the color function
def color(df, subset=column_list, up=5, low=-5):
    tmp = df[column_list].sub(pd.to_numeric(df['Unnamed: 2'], errors='coerce'), axis=0)
    return pd.DataFrame(np.select([tmp.gt(up), tmp.lt(low)],
                                  ['background-color: #e6ffe6;',
                                   'background-color: #ffe6e6;'],
                                  None), columns=subset, index=df.index
                       ).reindex_like(df)

df.style.apply(color, axis=None).to_excel('result.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', index=False)
```

Comment: You completely changed your code! You will **have to** use openpyxl to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is not fully clear behind the colored cells in your expected output.

Anyway, to read/conditionally format/write a range of cells (*on the same file*), use this:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('filename.xlsx')

worksheet = workbook['Sheet1']

for row in worksheet.iter_rows(min_row=3, min_col=3, max_col=9):
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value == 1: # <-- change the condition(s) here
            cell.fill = PatternFill(start_color='FFFF00', end_color='FFFF00', fill_type='solid')

workbook.save('filename.xlsx') # here, we write on the same file while keeping/updating the old F.
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, there has been a change in the code that I inquired about. Could you please check again?

Comment: So why you had an openpyxl code at first ? Anyway, you can't use pandas (*eventually* [`ExcelWriter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html)) to write on an existing spreadsheet while keeping the old formatting settings, data, .. (even with `mode=a, if_sheet_exists="overlay"`) but you can do it with openpyxl though.

Comment: How can I control a dataframe without pandas?

Answer (score -1):

I used the below given code and it kept the formatting and also changed the cell color on condition.
Using pandas 1.5.2 (i dont think it has something to do with it)
and openpyxl 3.0.9. It keep the meger, border, font style, weight, family and color as it was in test file.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')

worksheet = workbook['Sheet1']
for row in worksheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, min_col=1, max_col=3):
   if row[0].value > 1:
      row[2].fill = PatternFill(start_color="FDFF00", end_color="FDFF00", fill_type='solid')

workbook.save('newfilename.xlsx')
```

[image: Original Test sheet]

[image: After change]

[image: Borders, merge cells, and other styles included in result file]

Comment: @lbraheem Azeem Thank you for your response. However, there has been a change in the code that I inquired about. Could you please check again?